# Как добавить файлы в .gitignore? Появляются файлы 15\Server\sqlite3\storage.ide-shm

Tags: visual-studio, git, sqlite3

После открытия проэкта в VS 2017, в локальном репозитории самопроизвольно добавляются 2 файла:

**F:.vs\Project_Name\v15\Server\sqlite3\storage.ide-shm
F:.vs\Project_Name\v15\Server\sqlite3\storage.ide-wal**

Папку .vs я добавил в gitignore, но git игнорирует это.
Также не помогает git reset.
Помогает: закрытие студии, рестарт пк, удаление файлов из папки.
Но это неудобно, такой каламбур мешает переключать ветки и т.д.

Кто сталкивался, что за файлы, как исправить ?

При  вводе команды
git reset

Unstaged changes after reset:
M       .vs/v15/Server/sqlite3/storage.ide-shm
M       .vs/v15/Server/sqlite3/storage.ide-wal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В gitignore чтобы игнорировать папку должно быть написано: `.vs/`

Чтобы git папку больше не отслеживал, выполните команду:
`git rm -r .vs`

Если вы не хотите отслеживать папку `reset` не поможет. `reset` (без опций) сбрасывает коммит и удаляет файлы из индекса.

Comment: Я указал в файле .gitignore - .vs/ , но это не сработало. В вопросе я этот момент озвучил и указал что вывело после команды git reset. И после команды git reset никакого сброса не произошло и файлы не удалились.

Comment: `git reset` (без --hard) не удаляет файлы из файловой системы. Эти файлы нужны VS 2017, она их создавать не перестанет. Чтобы они вам не мешали в репозитории 
(не на файловой системе) надо добавить  их в gitignor (что вы сделали) + сказать гиту чтобы он их не отслеживал `git rm`

Comment: Что означает опция -r ?

Comment: Рекурсивно (указанная папка + все файлы в ней)